# Is this a drawback for Ajax live search or a issue with the server

Tags: php, ajax

I have a live search bar on my website. Today I tried to check the site security. In the search bar I kept on inputting data (words for search) continously and after some time my server crashed and was down. Are there any precautions that can be helpful in solution for this problem? 
Working of the live search:Data by input is directed to a javascript function via

```
onkeyup()
```

Gets the value input and makes an Ajax call to the server and with

```
SELECT and LIKE
```

statements, selects the data form db and returns it back to the javascript where it displays the results on the screen.

Maybe I need to make some adjustments and checking before sending it to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 2 problems with your aproach:

- First you send one request for each typed char. Depending on the traffic of your site it could be a lot of requests.
- If you don't check what you're sending some malicious user can attack it easily with an SQL injection. Like...what happens if the users searches for "'a';DROP TABLE users; SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE 't' = 't';" ?

I advise you to use onsubmit instead of onkeyup and check what is entered before sending the query.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have used mysql real escape string before execution of the query. Another thing, will the search style will be the same with onsubmit? I mean the search will not be live anymore?

Comment: The results will only apear when you press enter or click submit button. To make a 'live' search as you're calling it, you need your server to be able to process the queries that were sent before and finish them appropriately. Like a pool of connections that are checked if they are still relevant or something non-trivial like this.